# How to get outputs of all intermediate layers of a deep RNN in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to obtain the outputs of every layer of a custom RNN model in Keras. The code for the model is given below.

```py
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import RNN, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np


class MinimalRNNCell(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        h = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
        output = h + K.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]


cells = [MinimalRNNCell(32), MinimalRNNCell(64)]
x = keras.Input((None, 257))
y = RNN(cells)(x)
out = Dense(257, name='fin_dense')(y)
out = Activation('sigmoid', name='out_layer')(out)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=out)
```

I can get the predictions using,

```py
in_test = np.random.randn(1, 3, 257)
mod_out = model.predict(in_test)
```

But I would like the outputs of every layer and when I try using the `getLayerOutputs` function which works for all other Keras models

```py
def getLayerOutputs(model, input_data, learning_phase=1):
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[1:]] # exclude Input
    layers_fn = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], outputs)
    return layers_fn([input_data, learning_phase])

layer_outs = getLayerOutputs(model, in_test)
```

I get the output of the entire RNN layer and not each cell within it, how do I get the output of each cell with the RNN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing return_state flag as `True` like so

```py
y = RNN(cells, return_state=True)(x)
```

We get output states of every cell of the RNN as a list

Answer (score 0):

This should do it on tensorflow 1.x (test version 1.12.0):

```
sess = K.get_session()

outs = dict() 
for i in range(1, len(model.layers)): 
    outs[model.layers[i].name] = sess.run([model.layers[i].output], feed_dict={model.input:in_test})
```

(outs has the intermediate results for each layer)

If you are using TensorFlow 2 (test version 2.0.0-rc1):

```
outs = dict() 
for i in range(1, len(model.layers)): 
    outs[model.layers[i].name] = Model(x, model.layers[i].output).predict(in_test)
```

Comment: This does not work, here is the error message: Traceback:
  File "/home/xyz/QuantizedNeuralNetworks-Keras-Tensorflow/test.py", line 63, in <module>
    outs[model.layers[i].name] = sess.run([model.layers[i].output], feed_dict={model.input: in_test})
  File "/home/xyz/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 713, in __hash__
    raise TypeError("Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. "
TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.

Comment: It works perfectly on TensorFlow 1.12.0. I did reproduce your problem using 2.0.0. I guess that you are working with this version (or maybe 1.14, I did not try that). I would ask you to remove the downvote as you did not specify which version of tf you are using.

Comment: I edit my comment adding a solution for tf 2 and specifying that the first one works on tf 1.12.0.